# Is ${a'(x-\mu)\over\sqrt{a'\Sigma a}}$ normal when $x$ is multivariate normal and $a$ is independent of $x$?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, independence, multivariate-normal-distribution

Is it true that

> If $a$ is random vector independent of $x$ for which $P(a'\Sigma a=0)=0$, then $$f\sim N(0,1)$$ and $f$ is independent of $a$ ?

Here $x\sim  N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ and $f={a'(x-\mu)\over\sqrt{a'\Sigma a}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is indeed standard normal and independent of $a$.

To simplify notation, define $y=x-\mu$.  Then $y\sim  N_p(0,\Sigma)$ with multivariate characteristic function $\varphi_y (t)=\exp(-\frac{1}{2} t' \Sigma t)$. The (univariate!) characteristic function of $f$ can be computed by conditioning on $a$... $$\varphi_f (t)=\mathrm E[\exp(itf)]=\mathrm E[\mathrm E[\exp(itf)|a]] $$ 
Now $\mathrm E[\exp(itf)|a]=\mathrm E[\exp(ita'y/\sqrt{a'\Sigma a})|a]=\varphi_y (ta/\sqrt{a'\Sigma a})=\exp(-t^2/2)$, where $\varphi_y$ is the multivariate characteristic function of $y$, because we can think of $a$ as if it were a constant (see Did's nice answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73353/conditional-expectation-of-function-of-two-rvs-one-measurable-one-independent) for a detailed justification of this). Therefore we find that $$\varphi_f (t)=\mathrm E[\exp(-t^2/2)]=\exp(-t^2/2)$$ Hence $f$ must be standard normal. It is also clear that, conditional on $a$, $f|a\sim N(0,1)$, which implies that $f$ is independent of $a$.